# PyQGIS method to add multiple GDB files?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, file-geodatabase

I can use the following to add multiple shapefiles to QGIS:

```
import os, glob

layers=[]
shape_path = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\Shapefiles\\"
for shape in glob.glob(shape_path + "*.shp"):
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(shape, os.path.basename(shape), "ogr")
    layers.append(layer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```

However, I have dozens of **.gdb folders** which I would like to add automatically (I can do this individually through *Layer > Add Vector Layer* but would be quite tedious).

Is there a similar, or albeit another, method using PyQGIS to add multiple GDB files?

Comment: Change `.shp` to `.GDB`?

Comment: @NathanW - Thanks Nathan but already tried that, didn't work.

Comment: File geodatabase is a *container*, not a data file.  There could be many (hundreds, thousands, millions) tables within that container, and some of them may not have geometry.

Comment: @Vince - Thanks Vince for adding that, it makes it a lot more clear. You're right in that there's quite a few tables within each container that I have, hence the 'need' to add them programmatically :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This aims to be a generic answer.

If you are able to load a layer in QGIS you can query its *uri* through the python console:

```
iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
```

in the printed uri you can easily tell, which part of the uri should be dynamically created and write python logic that substitutes this part, e.g. with `glob` results.

The first parameter passed to the `QgsVectorLayer` constructor is nothing but this uri. The second parameter is the human readable layer name, the third parameter a provider key. The provider key can be queried with

```
iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().name()
```

For .gdb the provider key is also 'ogr'.

---

```
> iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
u'/home/user/geodata/demo.gdb|layername=TOWNSSURVEY_POLYM'
> l=QgsVectorLayer(u'/home/user/geodata/demo.gdb|layername=TOWNSSURVEY_POLYM', 'survey', 'ogr' )
> l.isValid()
True
> QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([l])
[<qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x7f8c7610a808>]
```

Comment: Turns out I just needed to set the path before using `glob` but I will accept your answer as it provides a more educational description :)

Comment: Strange, that should not be required (i.e. imagine QGIS changing its pwd whenever a new layer is added). I did not have to call `os.chdir`, see the pasted excerpt which works for me.

Comment: Thank you, your code also works for me. Good to know another method :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the practically similar method for shapefiles but the path must be set ***before*** using `glob`:

```
import os, glob

layers=[]
os.chdir("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Test\\Shapefiles")
for fname in glob.glob("*.gdb"):
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(fname, os.path.basename(fname), "ogr")
    layers.append(layer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
```

Hope this helps others!